# Display long text in single line in marqee formate without cutting text in android

Tags: android

I want to display long text in single line without cutting any text.
I have search many articles but does not worked.
I had try this code ,

marqee.xml in anim folder

```
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:duration="10000"
android:fromXDelta="100%"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
android:repeatCount="infinite"
android:repeatMode="restart"
android:toXDelta="-100%" />
```

demo.xml textview contains

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_tag_line"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:text=" I want to display long text in single line without cutting any text."
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:textSize="36sp"/>
```

demo.java in java file code is

```
 txt_tag_line = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txt_tag_line);

    txt_tag_line.startAnimation((Animation) AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(),R.anim.marqee));
```

please tell me how do I get Full moving text in single line without cutting any word.
thanks

Comment: I really don't get what you mean by "cutting text".

Comment: means some text are missing, Its show only that much text which hold by display when display size is short and text size is log then it cutting down text and show only hold by display size text

Comment: Oh I got you. I have the solution for that.

Comment: What is **v** in txt_tag_line = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txt_tag_line);

Comment: I am using in fragment so v is a object of view

Comment: You should try **getView().findViewById(R.id.txt_tag_line);**

Answer (score 0):

Use the following for your `TextView`

```
 <TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever" />
```

For the text to scroll automatically, you must call

```
txt_tag_line.setSelected(true);
```

There's no need for your custom animation.

Comment: and I want automatic moving text thats why need custom animation

Comment: @Ronitkadwane This solution is for automatic moving text. You need to call **myTextView.setSelected(true);** for the text to move.

Comment: This should work. This is the way. You must be doing something else wrong.

Comment: i had done exactly what you have mention but not working

Comment: @Ronitkadwane post your current code and xml with my suggestion implemented. Maybe I'll be able to see what you're doing wrong.

Comment: java code
  txt_tag_line = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txt_tag_line);

        txt_tag_line.setSelected(true);
xml

Comment: xml file
    <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_tag_line"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ellipsize="marquee"
                android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
                android:text="BreadLiner BreadLiner BreadLiner BreadLiner BreadLiner"/>

Comment: @Ronitkadwane So the problem is of no scrolling text now? Does your TextView move with your own original code though?

Comment: Problem is both,
neither  get my original text nor moving text